# Different LinqPad tabs acquires the same mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, linqpad

I'm testing some threading code, and using LinqPad I noticed that I'm able to acquire the same named Mutex from two different LinqPad tabs. After diagnosing for I while I realized that it only happens in LinqPad and not in regular code.

Any help why it happens? AFAIK LinqPad uses different App Domains to execute each tab but I'm not sure how that should change anything since I'm using a named mutex.

Here's the code:

```
var mutexName = @"Global\TestMutex".Dump();
var createdNew = false;
var mtx = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out createdNew);

(createdNew ? "I own the mutex" : "I don't own the mutex").Dump();

mtx.WaitOne();  // Not really necessary

"I aquired the mutex".Dump();

string.Format("PID: {0} ThreadID: {1} AppDomainID: {2}",
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id,
    AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId(),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id).Dump();
Util.ReadLine();
```

Paste this code into two LinqPad tabs and it will consistently reproduce the issue, sometimes you'd have to stop and start the second tab though.

Comment: Have you checked the options? There are some settings related to recycling app domains in there.

Comment: I wasn't aware of those options, but I just checked them and it shouldn't effect the outcome. Besides both tabs run simultaneously and regardless of the Thread or AppDomain they shouldn't not be able to acquire the same named Mutex at once

Comment: Since Joe Albahari (the author of LinqPad) has also written a book about threading, I'm sure he would be able to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mutex is being collected by the GC, so that the first program closes it before the second one starts.

Add `GC.KeepAlive(mtx)` after the `ReadLine` to force the Mutex to survive until then.

Comment: (My first answer was a misunderstanding)

Comment: It's not the `GC.KeepAlive(mtx)` that fixes the issue, since the code is not reached. It's that `mtx` is referenced in the code, adding `var type = mtx.GetType();` has the same effect. So basically, it's compiler optimization.

Comment: @Yona: That's what `KeepAlive` does.  It's a no-op method which simply forces it's caller to use a variable.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx

Comment: But `KeepAlive` is not executed since `Util.ReadLine()` blocks execution before that line is reached.

Comment: @Yona: The point of KeepAlive is to show the GC/JITter that the variable is used later.  Read the docs.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't know that and now I do. But the name and the `GC` class prefix is very misleading.

Comment: Yes; I once made the same mistake.